# Why are Amazon AWS Cloudwatch monitoring charts blank?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch

We run a handful of Amazon RDS and are usually able to view basic monitoring metrics (such as free space, freeable memory, CPU utilisation etc.) in the appropriate tab via the AWS Console.

At present, none of our RDS instance monitoring tabs shows any data. I've tried extending the window of time reported, but to no avail.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and, if so, what was the cause/how did you overcome it? Screenshot here:
[Missing Cloudwatch Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZJ7o.png)

EDIT: It's been this way for >36 hours and our account doesn't include technical support.

Comment: If you check in CloudWatch console?

Comment: Hi @Marcin - I can see the data there and that's good, but I wondered why the monitoring data is blank and if anyone else has seen this?

Workarounds are useful, but I'd like to figure out the cause/solution.

Comment: Maybe some RDS console glitch?

Comment: @Marcin - I did wonder that too. Hopefully, someone will be able to corroborate what I'm seeing so that I know it's not just us!!!

Comment: Currently a lot updates are rolled out on backend and frontend i guess, e.g. brand new S3 console. Have you tried to clear the browser cache?